# ¿Como castear un SelectItem a un Canvas?

Tags: java, smartgwt, gwt

Soy relativamente nuevo con java avanzado y estoy teniendo un problema al querer ingresar un Selectitem dentro de un Arraylist de Canvas e buscado en Internet si hay una forma de castearlo pero no eh tenido suerte espero y alguien me pueda ayudar con esta duda.

```
public Canvas[] getControls(){
    ArrayList<Canvas> a = new ArrayList<Canvas>();
            
    a.add(estatus());
        a.add(buscar());

    if(chkVista){
        a.add(vista());
    }
    a.add(prefer());
    a.add(formula());
    a.add(ordenar());
    a.add(expandir());
    a.add(comprimir());
    a.add(clear()); 
        
    return HelperArray.get().arrayToarrayCanvas(a);
}
```

En este caso al hacer **`a.add(estatus());`** me aparece:

> (the method add(canvas) in the type arraylist is not applicable for the arguments (selectitem))

Este es el código de mi *Selectitem*:

```
public SelectItem estatus() {
    SelectItem siEstatus = new SelectItem();
    siEstatus.setShowTitle(false);
    siEstatus.setWidth(300);
    return  siEstatus;
}
```

Comment: Hola Roberto, bienvenido, pregunta, **SelectItem** hereda de **Canvas**?.

Comment: Gracias, tengo entendido que no, dentro del arraylist de canvas los demas add agregan un toolstripbutton y aqui estoy intentando ingresar un selectitem

Comment: No estoy entendiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, pero cuando declaras **ArrayList<Canvas> a = new ArrayList<Canvas>();** solo le puedes agregar objetos tipo "Canvas", supongo que estás usando la clase "Canvas" de "AWT", si es así, no creo (no veo las clases) que nada de lo que agregas al "List" sea compatible.

Comment: La clase **Canvas** que estoy usando proviene de **smartgwt**

Comment: Entiendo, sin ver la estructura básica de tus clases, no puedo saber que es lo que pasa.

Answer (score 0):

Ya quedo resuelto el problema lo que hice fue crear un **dynamic form** y un **canvas**, al **dynamic form** le sete el componente en este caso era el **selectitem** y después al **canvas** le hice un ***addChild*** y le metí el form que previamente cree, de esta manera:

```
public Canvas estatusCanvas() {
    SelectItem siComponente = new SelectItem();
    siComponente.setName("Vista");
    siComponente.setShowTitle(true);
    siComponente.setWidth(200);

    DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
    form.setFields(siComponente);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.addChild(form);
    return canvas;
}
```